# Parsing every element of an array as an integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I have a string which I need to split into an array and then perform mathematical functions on each element of the array.

Currently I am doing something like this. (Actually, I am doing nothing like this, but this is a very simple example to explain my question!

```
var stringBits = theString.split('/');

var result = parseInt(stringBits[0]) + parseInt(stringBits[3]) / parseInt(stringBits[1]);
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way I can convert every element of an array into a certain type that would stop me from having to explicitly parse it each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just loop through it:

```
for(var i = 0; i < stringBits.length; i++) {

    stringBits[i] = parseInt(stringBits[i]);
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing that where possible, it seems like an unnecessary loop when really all it will do is make my code a little cleaner.

Comment: In JS, looping is the only way to do something with every entry of an array.

Comment: If all you want to do is make your code a little cleaner, you could provide a method (e.g. extractIntsFromString) that converts your string to an array of integers. Then use the elements of the integer array for your calculations. Once the type conversion out of the way, you can focus on the cleaner code that, now, just performs the mathematical functions.

Answer (score 11):

An easier method is to map to the Number object

```
result= stringBits.map(Number);
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Not that the other answers are not correct, but the simplicity of this is genius.

Comment: It's also more up to date (ES6)

Answer (score 4):

javascript 1.6. has map() ( https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Map ), so you can do something like

```
intArray = someArray.map(function(e) { return parseInt(e) })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
["1","2"].map(Number)
result: [1,2]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to provide a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you add a plus (+) sign in front of your strings they should be converted to numeric.

For example, this will print 3:

```
var x = "1";
var y = "2";
alert((+x) + (+y));
```

But I am not sure if this is portable to all browsers.

Your code will become:

```
var stringBits = theString.split('/');
var result = (+stringBits[0]) + (+stringBits[3]) / (+stringBits[1]);
```

But this is just a hack, so use with care.

I think the `parseInt` states better what you are trying to do, but you should delegate this responsibility to another method that returns the final data that you need to process. Convert and then process, don’t convert while processing. Your code will be easier to read.

Comment: What?!?!? Oh God!