# Calling .parseInt() on something that can't be parsed - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have an array of strings.

```
a = ['1', 'car', '2'];
```

I want to parse only the parsable elements, my objective is:

```
a = [1, 'car', 2];
```

How can I do that?
What does it happen when I try to parse a[1] ?

Comment: use `isNaN`. that function checks if the input is not a number

Comment: `What does it happen when I try to parse ...` - You could have tried that yourself

Comment: really? that's a pretty useful answer

Comment: Like @Mouser suggests: use a loop and isNan

Comment: Before you accept an answer, why don't you check it and make sure it actually does what you are asking. The one you accepted does not. It does not even create an array. The object it does create does not contain the non-numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the purpose of the question has become more clear now, an edit:

```js
     var a = ["1", 'car', 2];
     a = a.map(function(element) {
       //check if element is a number and not NaN or empty string
       if (!isNaN(element) && element != "") {
          return parseInt(element, 10);
       }
       else
       {
          return element;
       }
     });

     document.body.textContent = a;
```

This will traverse your array. Testing if the array element is a number, if so transform the number if possible. I'm using `Array.prototype.map` for this. Please note that this only filters integers. If you want to filter floats use `parseFloat`. That will parse integers and floats.

Comment: You don't need `isNan(parseInt(element))`; `isNaN(element)` will work fine byitself. Anyway, he doesn't want to filter the array, he wants to convert to numbers where possible.

Comment: @torazaburo, still this now map the integers, converting strings to integers where possible and skipping values that are not

Comment: Must be missing something. Your solution doesn't transform or replace anything, it just counts the numbers in the array. If that's all you wanted to do, it could be just `a.length - a.filter(isNaN).length`.

Comment: @torazaburo It isn't entirely clear what the OP wants parsed. Should the array contain only numbers or should all items that can be converted to a number be converted and the rest left untouched?

Comment: You don't need `isNaN(parseInt(...`, just `isNan(element)` will do fine.

Comment: Be careful with this method and empty strings. `!isNaN("")` resolves to true, which is unexpected

Comment: @camiblanch, thank you, updated this to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
a.map(function(x) { return +x || x; })
```

`+x` will try to convert the value to a number, and return `NaN` if it fails. That is falsy, and cause the RHS of the `||` to be evaluated, returning the original value.

However, this will fail on `'0'`, so you need to do

```
a.map(function(x) { return isNaN(x) ? x : +x; }
```

It's a bit more compact in ES6 environments:

```
a.map(x => isNaN(x) ? x : +x);
```

Comment: `+'0'` is falsy but definitely a parsable number.

Answer (score -1):

For this you have to loop for each value and check the parse int or not. Here is sample example and create another array.

```
var count_a = {};
for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++)
    { 
        if (!isNaN(a[i]))
        { 
           count_a[i] = parseInt(a[i], 10);
        }
        else { count_a[i] = a[i] }
    }
    a = count_a
```

or as first link below you can try this. whenever you want to use of array element.

```
var a = ['1','2','3'];
var result = a.map(function (x) { 
    return parseInt(x, 10); 
});
```

[How to convert all elements in an array to integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437916/to-convert-all-elements-in-an-array-to-integer-in-javascript)

[Parsing every element of an array as an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769649/parsing-every-element-of-an-array-as-an-integer)

Comment: will a become   [ 1,  'nan', 2 ] ?

Comment: no, will be ['1','2']. if you wish 'car' index shoulb be there , so you can add '0' when if condition not satisfy.

Comment: I think you mean `if (!isNaN...)` (note `!`).

Comment: You are using object, not an array. Why?

Comment: I wonder if you tested this. It will create an object `count_a` which contains values only for numeric entries. That's not what the OP said he wanted.

Answer (score -2):

Array construction:

```
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 'car';
a[2] = 2;
```

You need an indexed array.